# Filter a column which has multilevel column header in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have an excel like below

[image]

```
A   B   C   
        x   y
1   abc 3   5
2   abc 4   6
1   def 5   7
1   qrs 6   8
2   def 7   9
```

When I read this with pandas using the code `df= pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\mys2kor\Desktop\Mappe1.xlsx',engine='openpyxl',header=[0,1])`

I get the dataframe like so

```
A   B   C
Unnamed: 0_level_1  Unnamed: 1_level_1  x   y
1   abc     3   5
2   abc     4   6
1   def     5   7
1   qrs     6   8
2   def     7   9
```

[image]

I want to filter Column a for 1 and column B for 'def' & get just one row as output.

When I do `df["A"].filter(like="Unnamed")==1` and  `df["B"].filter(like="Unnamed")=='def'` separately, I get the proper boolean values

```
Unnamed: 0_level_1
True
False
True
True
False
```

and

```
Unnamed: 1_level_1
False
False
True
False
True
```

But when I put them together like so `(df["A"].filter(like="Unnamed")==1) & (df["B"].filter(like="Unnamed")=='def')`, I get like below!

```
Unnamed: 0_level_1  Unnamed: 1_level_1
False   False
False   False
False   False
False   False
False   False
```

How do I filter such that the output is

```
A   B   C   
        x   y
1   def 5   7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could use the columns `A` and `B` as index while reading the excel file, then use indexing with `loc` to query the index values:

```
df = pd.read_excel('...', header=[0, 1], index_col=[0, 1])
df.loc[[(1, 'def')]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this by columns names? I ask because sometimes, we do not know the column index, we know just the column name.

Comment: @moys Aa far as I know, you can not specify the names for index while reading the excel file although this is possible while reading the csv file.